# How to decode voip audio when G711 and G729 comes together in single stream?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, voip, rtp

I am developing a voip call recording system in c#. I have used **ffmpeg.exe** to decode the streams.

what i have done till now is that catch all incoming and outgoing rtp packets and write to sepperate files(only the payload part). And by **ffmpeg** i used to convert into mp3 each then mix both the incoming and outgoing audio.

And now i found out that in single stream both the **g729 and g711** codecs are coming. The decoding commands are different for both the codecs.

So i need to decode both seperately. But i dont know how will i overcome this issue.

Can anyone suggest me a solution ?

I am using **Wireshark** to analyse the packets.

**Edit**

Below i added  filter details
[image]
[image]

Is there any open source softwares for call recording other than oreca ?

Thank you.

Comment: Using two codecs in a single audio stream seems like a weird thing to do.  Which application is that?  You'll have to run the packets through the appropriate decoder and stitch the decoded output blocks together again.

Comment: I just filtered with RTP port number in wireshark that gives me two different codecs. It was in the following order g729,g711 then again g729. Its broadworks user.

Comment: Did you find any solution?